# ADO Provider: Data source name not found

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I know this question has been asked before but I can't get the recommendations from previous posts to work.

Below you can see my code which I think is more or less working properly but I always get an error for the data source name.

Any help on that would be very much appreciated!

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, i As Long

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider = MSDASQL;" &_
      "Data Source = C:\Users\ablohn\Documents\Database2.accdb"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "NameofTable", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic,    adCmdTable

    For i = 1 To 10 
        x = 0

        Do While Len(Range("A" & i).Offset(0, x).Formula > 0
            With rs
                .AddNew
                .Fields("Name1") = Range ("A" & i).Value
                'repeated for as many times as needed
                .Update
            End With
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    Next i

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you create such a datasource? And as far as I remember there is a difference in datasources for 32 and 64 bit. So the datasource should be created according to the architecture (32/64bit) of Microsoft Office. Edit: I see right now, that you aren't really talking about DataSources stored in Windows.

Comment: As you can see here `https://www.vlsoftware.net/documentation/exportizer/connection-strings-examples.htm` you maybe should use a different type of connection string for `accdb`?

Comment: @UnhandledException I am talking about data sources stored in windows. As the data source name i have to fill in the name of the access table, don't I? I am trying to push data from an Excel Sheet to Access (and update a SharePoint list form there)

Comment: Did you succeed with any of the answers?

Comment: @Asger no unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `select into` or `insert into`

like this, where f1 is column 1(A) and f3 is column 3(C)

`select f1,f3 INTO tbl1 FROM [EXCEL 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Workspace\test_data1.xlsx].[sheet1$]`

or

`insert into tbl1 SELECT f1,f3 FROM [EXCEL 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Workspace\test_data1.xlsx].[sheet1$]`